# Rails rspec tests are failing in Docker and CI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, unit-testing, rspec-rails, database-cleaner

When I run `rspec` localy all specs pass.

When I run all specs in **Docker** or **CI**, they fail. However, when I run them in isolation, they pass.
Another thing to mention is that every time I have different set of specs failing.

Environment setup:

```
ruby 2.2.2
rails 4.2.0
postgres 9.3
(using ActiveRecord)
gems:
    database_cleaner 1.4.1
    fabrication 2.14.0
    faker 1.4.3
```

The problem may be with `database_cleaner` settings.

```
# database_cleaner.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:deletion)
    Rake::Task["create_mailers"].invoke
  end

  config.around(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = example.metadata[:js] ? :deletion: :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
      example.run
    end
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    Capybara.reset_sessions!
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

So my question is, how do I make my tests pass in **Docker** and **CI**?

Comment: Hey man, what i can tell is that you use DatabaseCleaner.cleaning OR DatabaseCleaner.clean, not both. At least thats what the docs are telling. Maybe you can sort that out and report back.

Comment: @jfornoff, thanks for response! Unfortunately this didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Can you share more info? Are there any error messages?